# Getting an exit status stored to a variable inside an ssh command

Tags: bash, if-statement, ssh

I am trying to check that status of a prior command in list of commands sent to a server to change the password. When I just `echo $?` it works. when I store it to a variable like `STATUS=$?` and then `echo $STATUS` I get a blank line. And when I place the `echo $?` inside my if loop then returns something weird also. Below is the code of the ssh command for any advise on how to get this fixed.

```
ssh root@192.168.56.13 "printf '%s\n%s' "$PASSWORD" "$PASSCONFIRM" | passwd; STATUS=$?; echo $STATUS; if (( $STATUS == 0 )); then printf 'Password Changed Successfully\n'; else printf 'Password Change Unsuccessful\n'; fi; sleep 1;"
Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: password updated successfully

Password Change Unsuccessful
bash: ((: == 0 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "== 0 ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to scape the variables you want to use in the remote server.

`$PASSWORD` and `$PASSWORDCONFIRM` are fine, those are used in the local server.

`$STATUS` and `$?` you want then to be evaluated in the remote server, so you will need to scape them: `STATUS=\$?`, `echo \$STATUS` and `if (( \$STATUS == 0))`

Comment: You are my hero, after posting I figure out the escaping of the `echo \$STATUS` and `if (( \$STATUS == 0 ))` but I didn't think of escaping it when storing it like `STATUS=\$?` Thanks so much!

Comment: I am glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

First, the variable references (like `$STATUS`) are getting expanded by the local shell, before the command is even sent to the remote computer, let alone executed. To prevent this, you need to escape the `$` (e.g. `\$STATUS`) so it just gets passed to the remote system rather than interpreted locally.

Second, quotes don't nest. You're trying to nest double-quotes inside a double-quoted string, and that doesn't work; you need to escape the inner double-quotes (just like the `$`).

You can test this by using `echo` instead of `ssh`. Normally, this is a bad way to tell what's going on with a shell command, because `echo` shows what the arguments look like *after* they've been through the shell parsing process. But in this case that's exactly what'll get sent to the remote system, so it's what you want. Here's an example:

```
$ PASSWORD='p4ssw0rd'
$ PASSCONFIRM='p4ssw0rd'
$ echo "printf '%s\n%s' "$PASSWORD" "$PASSCONFIRM" | passwd; STATUS=$?; echo $STATUS; if (( $STATUS == 0 )); then printf 'Password Changed Successfully\n'; else printf 'Password Change Unsuccessful\n'; fi; sleep 1;"
printf '%s\n%s' p4ssw0rd p4ssw0rd | passwd; STATUS=0; echo ; if ((  == 0 )); then printf 'Password Changed Successfully\n'; else printf 'Password Change Unsuccessful\n'; fi; sleep 1;
```

Note the "`STATUS=0; echo ; if ((  == 0 ))`" -- that's because all the variable references (`$?` and `$STATUS`) got expanded locally, to 0 and "" respectively. Here's a version with appropriate escapes added:

```
$ echo "printf '%s\n%s' \"$PASSWORD\" \"$PASSCONFIRM\" | passwd; STATUS=\$?; echo \$STATUS; if (( \$STATUS == 0 )); then printf 'Password Changed Successfully\n'; else printf 'Password Change Unsuccessful\n'; fi; sleep 1;"
printf '%s\n%s' "p4ssw0rd" "p4ssw0rd" | passwd; STATUS=$?; echo $STATUS; if (( $STATUS == 0 )); then printf 'Password Changed Successfully\n'; else printf 'Password Change Unsuccessful\n'; fi; sleep 1;
```

BTW, note that I'm assuming `PASSWORD` and `PASSCONFIRM` are local, and *should* be expanded locally, so I didn't escape the `$` on those. But there's a potential problem: if either value contains anything that's interpreted inside double-quotes, the remote shell *will* interpret it. So for example if your password is `p4$$w0rd`, the `$$` will get replaced by the process ID of the remote shell. Using single-quotes around them would be better, but if they contain single-quotes, chaos will result:

```
$ PASSWORD="p4'\$\$w0rd"
$ echo "$PASSWORD"    # show the true password
p4'$$w0rd
$
$ # This will not work right, because of the $$:
$ echo "printf '%s\n%s' \"$PASSWORD\" \"$PASSCONFIRM\" ..."
printf '%s\n%s' "p4'$$w0rd" "p4ssw0rd" ...
$
$ # Neither will this, because of the single-quote:
$ echo "printf '%s\n%s' '$PASSWORD' '$PASSCONFIRM' ..."
printf '%s\n%s' 'p4'$$w0rd' 'p4ssw0rd' ...
$
$ # But this, while messy, will work:
$ ESCAPEDPW=${PASSWORD//\'/\'\\\'\'}
$ ESCAPEDCONFIRM=${PASSCONFIRM//\'/\'\\\'\'}
$ echo "printf '%s\n%s' '$ESCAPEDPW' '$ESCAPEDCONFIRM' ..."
printf '%s\n%s' 'p4'\''$$w0rd' 'p4ssw0rd' ...
```

...wait, I hear you say, *that* will work? Yes, and here's a demo of what that password muddle is going to do on the remote system:

```
$ printf '%s\n%s' 'p4'\''$$w0rd' 'p4ssw0rd'
p4'$$w0rd
p4ssw0rd
```

(Note that they don't match because I didn't bother to update `PASSCONFIRM`.)